# Remote debugging runtime library in a JVM from a different vendor

Tags: java, jvm, remote-debugging, aix

Is there a good approach to remotely debug and step through **JVM classes** (think rt.jar) of the target JVM? For example if my main development environment is on Windows Oracle HotSpot JVM and I want to remotely debug the application running on the AIX IBM JVM? The bytecode/internal classes are different so the line numbers don't exactly match up to what my IDE is showing me.

Comment: osgi should provide remote debugging ports

Comment: You'll need the version of the code running on the remote VM. If the line numbers aren't correct then you won't have a lot of luck instrumenting the remote byte-code.

Comment: How could I get the version of the JVM classes on my Windows machine? I could pull rt.jar from AIX and add it to my classpath but I'm not sure if that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM offers their SDK for Windows here - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/java8/.